# Program type already present com.google.gson.FieldAttributes

Tags: java, android, gradle

My android app refuses to build with the following error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.gson.FieldAttributes
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.gson.FieldAttributes, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My build.gradle dependencies

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.github.Steveice10:MCProtocolLib:1.12.2-2'
    api 'com.github.Steveice10:OpenNBT:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Prefs:1.3' //Propably this cause problem
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }}
```

It probably started to happen when I added com.github.GrenderG:Prefs dependency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to build.gradle file.

```
configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

After 3 hours of googling around I finnaly found an Answer:
GPDR compilance library caused the problem

```
implementation ('com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6') {
                exclude module: 'gson'
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code to your *build.gradle(app)* -

```
dependencies {
    configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add Dependency to build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Comment: I had the same error when I tried to run an app with Gson, but I already had this line of code. I also tried the answer below, but the app still refused to run. Do you have any other suggestions?