# Gradle Build Error - Program type already present

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, gson

I'm trying to build an android project which has two modules, one is an application and the other is a library. Both modules have **gson-2.8.5.jar** files included in their respective ***libs*** folder. When I deploy the application, it fails during build with the following error message.

```
Program type already present: com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$6
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$6, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

However, I tested my setup by replacing hard provided .jar files dependencies with gradle's (**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'**) and it worked fine. But I have to use jar files in libs folder since I'm going to use **Android.mk** file to build the entire project later on, therefore can't depend on gradle injected dependency.

I searched about this error but unfortunately didn't find any useful results. Hope someone knows how to fix this.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116800/program-type-already-present-com-google-gson-fieldattributes

Comment: @AnubhavGupta As I said, I need to use gson from libs folder, so the referenced solution does not work for me since it relies on gradle injected dependency. I tried excluding gson from **implementation project** but didn't work

Comment: okk got it @waqaslam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it fixed. Seems like I had to mark `transitive` property to `false` for my included module.

Before:

```
implementation project(path: ':myLib')
```

After (fix):

```
implementation project(path: ':myLib', transitive: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with library:

```
implementation project(':library')
debugImplementation project(':library')
releaseImplementation 'com.library:1.0.0'
```

With

```
./gradlew project:assembleRelease
```

Gives the error.

Solution:
`implementation project(':library')` should be removed.