# Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.JsonNull how to find the duplicated lib

Tags: android, duplicates, gson

In my app if ran  via the cable to the tab it is working perefectly but when creating a singed apk i got error 
Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.JsonNull

here is the gradle  dependancies that are used for the application development

```
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }


}



repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

//configurations.all{ exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson' }
dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':ZeebraLibrary')
    implementation project(':MPChartLib')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0'

    implementation ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2')

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'){
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jackandphantom.android:circularprogressbar:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.2'
    implementation group: 'net.vidageek', name: 'mirror', version: '1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.6.2'
}
```

Please help me with explain how can I catch the duplicated lib on the android studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program type already present com.google.gson.FieldAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116800/program-type-already-present-com-google-gson-fieldattributes)

Comment: @ Md. Asaduzzama Yes it does solve  my issue with creating APK but then my all the gson related code base gives run time error  for exaomple Retrofit Converter gives reader gson error

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command in an android terminal for finding duplicate class/library

```
gradlew <projectname>:dependencies
```

Eg: ./gradlew app:dependencies