# Android Program type already present: com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter

Tags: android

I cann't seem to resolve this issue.Any solution for it?

I get this error when i am creating release build.In debug mode the project is working fine.I tried many solution but it cann't seem to be working.Any help will be appreciated.Please let me know if anything else is needed?

```
 Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter
```

This is my gradle in module-level:

```
  compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sms.instant"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 152
            versionName '5.6.7'
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }


     buildTypes {

            release {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true

                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    }

     lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility 1.8
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
        }
    `dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.an.customfontview:customfont:0.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.3'

        implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.github.lolucosmin:PermissionsWrapper:version_1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

        /* dagger dependency for DI*/
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13"
        annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"
        compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
        implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

        /*RxJava lib*/
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
        implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8"
        implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
        implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'


        /* LiveData lib*/
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
        implementation 'im.crisp:crisp-sdk:0.1.14'
        implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
        implementation('com.shagi:material-datepicker:1.3') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }
        implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
        implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
        implementation project(path: ':fingpay')
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your gradle file showing libraries.

```
 implementation ('com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6') {
                exclude module: 'gson'
 }
```

You have to try something like this. One of the library causing conflict because already in it. Thanks
[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116800/program-type-already-present-com-google-gson-fieldattributes)

Comment: I tried this solution and i am getting this.Program type already present: com.google.gson.annotations.Expose